# Intersecting rectangles from array

Tags: c#, forms, intersection, rectangles, intersect

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < pala.cantLetras; i++)
    {   guiones[i] = new Label();
        guiones[i].Text = "_";
        guiones[i].Font = new Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 25);
        guiones[i].Size = new Size(18, 37);
        guiones[i].Name = "guion" + i;
        guiones[i].ForeColor = Color.Black;
        guiones[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        guiones[i].Location = new Point(x, 341);
        this.Controls.Add(guiones[i]);

        recguion[i] = guiones[i].Bounds;
        recguion[i] = new Rectangle();
        //recguion[i].Location = new Point(x, 341);
        x = x + 50;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pala.cantLetras; i++)
    {
        labels[i] = new Label();
        labels[i].Size = new Size(25, 55);
        labels[i].Name = "label" + i;
        labels[i].Text = pala.palabra[i].ToString();
        labels[i].Font = new Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 20);
        labels[i].ForeColor = Color.Black;
        labels[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        labels[i].Location = new Point(y, 165);
        this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
        posRandom[i] = y;

        reclabel[i] = labels[i].Bounds;
        reclabel[i] = new Rectangle();

       // reclabel[i].Location = new Point(y, 165);

        y = y + 40;

    }

}
```

I need to know when reclabel[] intersects the recguion[] corresponding to that number. 
Ex: reclabel[1] Intersects recguion[1] but only that one, if it intersects another it has to say that it's wrong.
The rectangles have inside(or that's what I a'm trying) labels[] and guiones[]
This is what I have tryied but it doesnt work.

```
private void intersecta()
{
    int cont = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pala.cantLetras; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pala.cantLetras; j++)
        {
            if (i==j)
            {
                Rectangle intersect = Rectangle.Intersect(reclabel[i],         recguion[j]);
                if (intersect != Rectangle.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Intersection!");
                    cont++;
                }

            }
            if (cont != 0)
            {
                i = pala.cantLetras - 1;
                j = pala.cantLetras - 1;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no need for a nested loop.  Just loop through one array and check both rectangles at that index with `.IntersectsWith`.

Comment: You set `recguion[i] = guiones[i].Bounds;` and then immediately write over it with `recguion[i] = new Rectangle();`, which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a nested loop. Just loop through one array and check both rectangles at that index with `.IntersectsWith`.  My apologies if there are any syntax errors, I don't have access to Visual Studio at the moment.

```
For(int i = 0; i < Array1.Length; i++)
{
    if(Array1[i].IntersectsWith(Array2[i]))
    {
        //Intersected
    }
}
```

But also, as Andrew pointed out, you have a serious problem here:

```
reclabel[i] = new Rectangle();
```

You are just overwriting all your data with a new instance (of a different type!).

Comment: I've tried doing that but it doens't work I don't know what else to do. Thank you really much